# Dynamic measure for nonblank rows Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a bar chart with the count of nonblank rows as values and the column headers on the axis.

I've created some 'hard-coded' measures that look at each of the columns, e.g.:

```
COUNTBLANK(Planning[Actual_ClosingMeeting])
```

but when charting they are clustered together under a single axis value.

I was thinking if I could create a measure that looked at nonblank rows I could chart that and the axis would work as a filter? Perhaps this approach isn't the solution though.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give a minimal example table and what your desired result to be?

Comment: Hi I've been trying but not very good at working out the formatting in the post (not a great portent for my coding abilities..).

Comment: ActualClosingMeeting ActualDraftMeeting ActualEndMeeting
09/03/2018 16/03/2018 16/02/2018
16/02/2018 23/02/2018 23/02/2018
 05/01/2018 
 22/12/2017 19/01/2018
  
27/10/2017 10/11/2017 10/11/2017
  
06/10/2017 27/10/2017 27/10/2017
  23/02/2018
21/12/2017 05/01/2018 02/04/2018
21/07/2017  28/10/2017
14/07/2017 21/07/2017 21/07/2017

Comment: Sorry, keep hitting return as well - I'll get there sorry. It's basically just three columns with rows of dates with blanks in some rows. There are other rows in the table but it's these ones I wish to summarise. The result would be a count against each column name, which I'd use in a bar chart with column names on the axis and the measure as the values. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please edit the post rather than putting data in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possible way to do this (there are probably better ones if you've got many columns you want to chart rather than a handful):

---

Create a new table (Home > Enter Data) that has a single column containing all the different headers that you want on your column chart. E.g.

```
MeetingType
-----------
Closing
Draft
End
```

Once you have that defined, create a new calculated column (Modeling > New Colum) which counts the blanks corresponding to the different columns using a `SWITCH` function.

```
Count = SWITCH(MeetingType[MeetingType],
           "Closing", COUNTBLANK(Planning[ActualClosingMeeting]),
           "Draft", COUNTBLANK(Planning[ActualDraftMeeting]),
           "End", COUNTBLANK(Planning[ActualEndMeeting]))
```

Now you can create a bar chart with `MeetingType[MeetingType]` on the axis and `MeetingType[Count]` in the values box.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. You're right I do want to use values from other columns. I'll try and figure that out. And I note what you say about data in comments

Comment: OK thanks - I've set up the table. Is there a way to filter it based on a slicer selection from another column in the original query?

Comment: @deethreenovice Calculated columns are not responsive to slicers. If you need the counts to be responsive to slicers, then you'll need to use a different approach.

Comment: Thanks Alexis. Funnily enough I was watching a tutorial last night that made me realise the same thing - they are calculated once at run time and then that's it!